# Is there a way to set PrimeNG AutoComplete to required?

Tags: primeng

PrimeNG's AutoComplete does not currently show a required attribute in the [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete). Is there a workaround way to do this? The p-autocomplete generates an span element containing an input field and button (for the dropdown menu). I need to be able to somehow make the input have the "required" attribute